# Switch from heroku gem to heroku-api topolbelt

Tags: heroku, rubygems

Heroku is so good at making things simple...but this...not so much.  How do you switch from the heroku gem to the new tool belt?  Here are the steps I have taken:

```
 $ heroku version: heroku-gem/2.32.5 (x86_64-darwin11.4.1) ruby/1.9.3 autoupdate
 removed 'gem "heroku"' from gem file
 added 'gem "heroku-api"' to gemfile
 deleted gemfile.lock
 $ bundle install
 installed toolbelt via the package installer
 $ heroku login ... returns "Authentication successful"
 $ heroku version: STILL RETURNS heroku-gem/2.32.5 (x86_64-darwin11.4.1) ruby/1.9.3 autoupdate
```

Two questions:

```
 #1 Why is my version still using the heroku-gem after taking the steps above?
 #2 Where do I put "heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => API_KEY)" for use with the heroku-api gem?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the gemfile.lock file didn't cut it.  I had to run gem uninstall heroku (which I had 9 version of)...  After that, heroku version showed to tool belt.